# Java action to happen after 2 mouse clicks

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouselistener

So I have made something like paint in windows.
And I have a problem with the color pick button. The problem is that after I click that button the program gets the color under the button and I can't click on the color that I want to pick. How can I do it so when I click on the mouse the 2nd time something will happen?

Main class:

```
  btnColorPicker.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {      
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             try {
                drawingArea.colorPicker();
            } catch (AWTException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
             System.out.println(drawingArea.colorPick);
        //   btnColorPicker.setEnabled(false);
          }
    });
```

Another class:

```
public void colorPicker() throws AWTException{
    Color currentColor;
    Robot ro=new Robot();
    if(!colorPick){
        colorPick=true;
    }
    if(colorPick){

         addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
             public void mouseAction(MouseEvent e)
             {                       

                 Point p = e.getLocationOnScreen();
                 cXpos=e.getX();
                 cYpos=e.getY();
                 System.out.println(cXpos+","+cYpos);
             }
         });


         currentColor=ro.getPixelColor(cXpos, cYpos);
         this.currentColor=currentColor;
    }
    //colorPick=false;

}
```

Sorry if it's kinda messy, I'm new to java

Answer (score 0):

```
public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent mouseEvent)
{
  if (2 == event.getClickCount()) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Comment: and where should I add that? Instead of the mouseAction function?

Comment: Yes, just insert it and add what you want to do.

Comment: It's not working really well. I have to click in the same place for the click count to increase. For what I want to do I need to click in 2 different places and the click count to increase. So I don't want like a double click. I want to click on the color pick button and then on the color

Comment: Yes, that's what a double click is, clicking twice in the same place. If you don't want that you need to implement your own click counter: Click 1: increment to 1, click 2 reset it to 0 and perform your custom double click action. also asynchronously after a certain delay you need to reset the counter to zero if no second click occurs. See Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.multiClickInterval");

Comment: But for your purpose why not just have two different click events, one that clicks on the color picker tool and changes the cursor mode and one that then selects the color.